# I have a function y(x) and have to solve $\frac{d\ln(y)}{d\ln(x)}$ How can I do that?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

My problem comes from thermodynamics. I am trying to solve the Peng-Robinson EOS equation to get the residual enthalpy. Then I have an function $a(\operatorname{Tr})$ that is
$$
a = \Bigl(1 + k \, \bigl( 1 - \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}} \bigr) \Bigr)^2.
$$
I need to solve
$$
\frac{d\ln(a)}{d\ln(\operatorname{Tr})}. 
$$
Any idea on how to proced?

Once I know how to manage the logarithm part of the diferential I can solve using numeric methods.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: If $a=f(T)$ with everything positive and $b=\log_e(a)$ and $S=\log_e(T)$ then $b=\log_e(f(e^S))$ and you can find $\frac{db}{dS}$ using the chain rule.  You may then want to substitute back

Comment: Henry thanks for the answer! But I can see how that gets me to a better situation. I mean how can I use the chain rule when my derivation variable is on a logarithmic scale?

Comment: Or you can just compute $$\dfrac{\frac{d\ln y}{dx}}{\frac{d\ln x}{dx}}=\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: If $y=x^{-1/2}$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac12x^{-3/2}$ so, unsurprisingly, $\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let : $$y = \ln(Tr) \implies Tr = e^y $$
and

$$ ln(a)=ln\Bigl(1 + k \, \bigl( 1 - \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}} \bigr) \Bigr)^2=2ln\Bigl(1 + k \, \bigl( 1 - \sqrt{\operatorname{e^y}} \bigr) \Bigr)$$

And therfore :
$$\frac{d\ln(a)}{d\ln(\operatorname{Tr})}=\frac{d\ln(a)}{dy}=\frac{2d\ln\Bigl(1 + k \, \bigl( 1 - \sqrt{\operatorname{e^y}} \bigr) \Bigr)}{dy}=\frac{-k\sqrt{e^y}}{\Bigl(1 + k \, \bigl( 1 - \sqrt{\operatorname{e^y}} \bigr) \Bigr)}$$

Finally :
$$\frac{d\ln(a)}{d\ln(\operatorname{Tr})}=\frac{-k\sqrt{Tr}}{\Bigl(1 + k \, \bigl( 1 - \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}} \bigr) \Bigr)}$$